# Forward all URL requests to another domain (and keep original requested path) - Htaccess or DNS?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns, redirect

I want to buy a new domain, and have it redirect all page requests, to another domain (`example.com`).

So if someone goes to `newexample.com/page-1`, he will get a 301/302 redirect to `example.com/page-1`

If I do this with `htaccess`, it means I need to buy hosting first, but maybe that's not necessary and I can do with some kind of DNS definitions?

If it would be with `htaccess`, Should it look something like this?:

```
###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
###
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a proxy server (`eg. Nginx, HAProxy`) will be a better option for this use case.